# having trouble removing an extra row from a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-html

I'm trying to dynamically create a table using JS and jQuery. (I know I can hard code it in html but I don't want to do that.)
I have an extra row at the table that I'm having trouble removing.
Can someone please provide an answer/answers on how best to solve this in my code?

My code is posted below.

```
var game = {
    matrix: [],
    startGame: function()
    {
        this.doDomStuff(); //build board
    },
    doDomStuff: function(row, column)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            var row = $('<div>');
            row.attr('id', 'data-row' + (i + 1));
            row.addClass('data-row');
            for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                var column = $('<div>');
                column.attr('id', 'data-column' + (j + 1));
                column.addClass('data-column');
                column.addClass('column');
                row.append(column);
            }
            $('body').prepend(row);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What row you want to delete and when?

Comment: how many rows should your "table" have at the end? note that you use "divs" and not "tables" -> you can do this, but you have to define more styles to get the view of a table with divs

Comment: If you're getting an extra row, why don't you just change `i < 7` to `i < 6`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a game, and each row can have its own logic and behaviour, so it will be faster to operate array neither DOM structure. If your logic will be more complecated, you will see the difference in perfomance. So, call the DOM structure if you are really need to update objects there. For example:

```
function SuperTable(){
    this.tablerows = [];
    this.DOMObject = $("body");
}

SuperTable.prototype.AddRow = function() {
    this.tablerows[this.tablerows.length] = new SuperRow(this.tablerows.length,this.DOMObject);
}

SuperTable.prototype.RemoveRow = function(rowIndex) {
    this.tablerows[rowIndex].DOMObject.remove(); // remove element from DOM
    this.tablerows.splice(rowIndex,1); // remove element from logic of the game
}

function SuperRow(rownumber,parent) {
    this.DOMObject = $("<div>");
    this.DOMObject.addClass('data-row');
    parent.prepend(this.DOMObject);
}

mytable = new SuperTable()
mytable.AddRow() // create row on 0 position
mytable.RemoveRow(0) // remove row from 0 position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery's `.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function. 
For example, if you want to remove the last row: `$("#data-row7").remove()`